# Converting to number with comma

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have this code below that works fine when the "numbers" have no commas, but when the cell has a comma it doesn't convert to number. I have tried with having numberformat to 0, or #.##0 and so on but nothing is working. How can I solve the problem?

```
 Sub convert()
        Range("C:C").Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
        With Selection
            Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: How is this data getting to the worksheet? For this to be happening, it is likely there is a discrepancy between the thousands and digital separators for your Windows Regional Settings, and the data on the Excel sheet.  That being the case, there may be other values that are being incorrectly translated into numbers and that would also need to be considered. You might be better off doing a data **IMPORT** and using the text import wizard to specify the thousands and decimal separators.

Answer (score 1):

Try this version:

```
Sub convert()
   Dim r As Range

   For Each r In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      With r
         .NumberFormat = "General"
         .Value = Replace(.Value, ",", "")
      End With
   Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub convert()
    With Columns(3)
        .Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: It will remove all charecter from

```
    Sub convert()
            Dim MyRange, cell As Range
            Set MyRange = Range("C:C")
            Dim MyNum

            For Each cell In MyRange
            If IsEmpty(cell) Then Exit For
                MyNum = getNumber(cell)
                cell.Value = MyNum
                MyNum = ""
            Next cell

            Range("C:C").Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
            With Selection
                Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End Sub
```

This is getNumber function:

```
 Public Function getNumber(fromThis As Range) As Double
                'Extract the number from a cell and return it.
                Dim retVal As String
                Dim ltr As String, i As Integer, european As Boolean

                retVal = ""
                getNumber = 0
                european = False


                    If fromThis.Value Like "*.*,*" Then
                    european = True
                End If

                For i = 1 To Len(fromThis)
                    ltr = Mid(fromThis, i, 1)
                    If IsNumeric(ltr) Then
                        retVal = retVal & ltr
               ElseIf ltr = "." And (Not european) And Len(retVal) > 0   hen
                        retVal = retVal & ltr
                    ElseIf ltr = "," And european And Len(retVal) > 0 Then
                        retVal = retVal & "."
                    End If
                Next i
                getNumber = CDbl(retVal)

            End Function
```